# Cocos2D+Box2D: Stack bodies that doesn´t fall?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

**EDIT 2: Problem solved! I can´t promise it will work with different settings, but by putting my block´s body density to 0, the stack of blocks did not fall when new blocks are added.**

I´m sorry about the poor title of the question, I´ll explain my problem closer here:

So, I´ve used Box2D and cocos2D to setup a simple project where two boxes stacks on top of each other (I´m planning to expand to 8-10 boxes). Right now, using a friction of 10.0f on each box, the box at the top still moves around a little. If I would add more boxes, the "tower" would fall and I don´t want that.

I want the boxes to use the gravity to move down, but I never ever want them to change there start x-value. 
So, how could I prevent my tower of boxes to fall over or prevent my boxes from moving in x-direction?

EDIT: Posting some code
This code creates on of the boxes, the other one just have a different sprite file.

```
CCSprite *block = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"red.png"];
block.position = ccp(200,380);
[self addChild:block];
//Body definition
b2BodyDef blockDef;
blockDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
blockDef.position.Set(200/PTM_RATIO, 200/PTM_RATIO);
blockDef.userData = block;
b2Body *blockBody = _world->CreateBody(&blockDef);
//Create the shape
b2PolygonShape blockShape;
blockShape.SetAsBox(block.contentSize.width/PTM_RATIO/2, block.contentSize.height/PTM_RATIO/2);
//Fixture defintion
b2FixtureDef blockFixtureDef;
blockFixtureDef.shape = &blockShape;
blockFixtureDef.restitution = 0.0f;
blockFixtureDef.density = 10.0f;
blockFixtureDef.friction = 10.0f;
_redBlockFixture = blockBody->CreateFixture(&blockFixtureDef);
```

Nothing fancy.

Regards.

Comment: Just to clarify, you mean you don't want them to move in the x direction, right?

Comment: Terrible sorry, of course I mean the x-direction. Post updated, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Please post your current code as well so we know how you set this up and have a sample to test ourselves.

Comment: Please add @Karl-JohanSjögren in your comment so that he gets notified that you have updated your post :)

Comment: Post updated with some code @Karl-JohanSjögren, thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

You could setup a 2 (1 pixel wide) walls in box2D to the left and right of the block.  Here's some sample code for the left wall.  To create the right wall, just copy and past the code and change the variable names and the position of the BodyDef.

```
// Constant you'll need to define
float wallHeight;

// Create wall body
b2BodyDef wallBodyDef;
wallBodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
wallBodyDef.position.Set(200 - block.contentSize.width/PTM_RATIO/2, 0);
b2Body *wallBody = _world->CreateBody(&wallBodyDef);

// Create wall shape
b2PolygonShape wallShape;
wallShape.SetAsBox(1, wallHeight);

// Create shape definition and add to body
b2FixtureDef wallShapeDef;
wallShapeDef.shape = &wallShape;
wallShapeDef.density = 100.0f;
wallShapeDef.friction = 0.0f;
wallShapeDef.restitution = 0.0f;
b2Fixture *wallFixture = wallBody->CreateFixture(&wallShapeDef);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for helping out. I actually solved this problem a while ago, by putting the block´s body density = 0, they did not "bounce" at all and therefore they don´t move in x-axis. The method you described is probably safer but I need collision detection on the blocks so a wall would not be good solution in my case!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adjusting the restitution (bounce) of the static surface upon which the blocks are stacked. For example, if the floor has a restitution of .2, a stack of five blocks will look like they are compressing into each other, and eventually topple:
[image: blocks start to "compress" and then topple]

Set the restitution of the floor to 0, and the blocks stay stacked the way you would expect:
[image: blocks stay stacked]